# RubyZip: archiving process indication

Tags: ruby, archive, rubyzip

I am adding tons of file to my archive it looks like this:

```
print "Starting ..."
Zip::ZipFile.open(myarchive, 'w') do |zipfile|
  my_tons_of_files.each do |file|
    print "Adding #{file.filename} to archive ... \r"
    # ...
  end
  print "\n Saving archive"
  # !!! -> waiting about 10-15 minutes
  # but I want to show the percentage of completed job
end
```

After all files are added to my archive it starts to compress them all (about 10-15 minutes).

How can I indicate what is actually going on with `rubyzip gem` (actually I want to show percentage like `current_file_number/total_files_count`).

Comment: Have you considered launching a thread to keep an eye on the zip file size as it is being built? That won't give you "compressing file 11 of 2342" but it will let you know that it is doing something.

Comment: @mu is too short, smart idea, thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override Zip::ZipFile.commit:

```
require 'zip'
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

module Zip
class ZipFile

    def commit
     return if ! commit_required?
      on_success_replace(name) {
        |tmpFile|
        ZipOutputStream.open(tmpFile) {
          |zos|

          total_files = @entrySet.length
          current_files = 1
          @entrySet.each do |e|
             puts "Current file: #{current_files}, Total files: #{total_files}"
             current_files += 1
             e.write_to_zip_output_stream(zos)
          end
          zos.comment = comment
        }
        true
      }
      initialize(name)
    end

end
end

print "Starting ..."
Zip::ZipFile.open(myarchive, 'w') do |zipfile|
```